# while running request in jmeter getting errors

Tags: jmeter

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_261]
```

and this one also

```
2020-10-22 16:33:41,633 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-10-22 16:33:41,634 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines:

> 2020-10-22 16:33:41,633 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 2020-10-22 16:33:41,634 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, local)

are absolutely normal, given [`INFO` log level](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm) they're **info**rmation messages which just let you know that the test has ended.

With regards to the first [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) block - it is not full so we cannot guess what is causing the problem, it might be the case you're suffering from [JMeter Bug 64479](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64479), if this is the case - just remove HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder from your test plan. If this is not the case - don't run JMeter test in GUI mode, it's only for tests development and debugging, you must use [JMeter command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) for test execution

Comment: but i need to use GUI and http request is getting hit without any error but still showing 3 errors and the previous one notifying unknown source.